# How to add PATH in shell script

Tags: powershell, shell

```sh
SRC_FILE=$1
BKP_FILE=$2
echo "SRC_FILE :" ${SRC_FILE}
echo "BKP_FILE :" ${BKP_FILE}
```

In the above code how can I give the direct path to `SRC_FILE` and `BKP_FILE`. like if I want to give the path say, "`app/retro/power/shell`" to `SRC_FILE` and "`app/retro/power/script`" to `BKP_FILE`.

How do I fit the above path to the script??

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass the argument when calling your script.

```
SRC_FILE=$1 BKP_FILE=$2 
echo "SRC_FILE :" ${SRC_FILE} 
echo "BKP_FILE :" ${BKP_FILE}
```

So the PATH for SRC_FILE and BKP_FILE should be passed like this :

```
./script.sh SRC_FILE BKP_FILE
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to write down the PATH directly into the code you would set the variables as follows:

```
SRC_FILE="app/retro/power/shell" BKP_FILE="app/retro/power/script" 
echo "SRC_FILE :" ${SRC_FILE} 
echo "BKP_FILE :" ${BKP_FILE}
```

Comment: I have to give the path "app/retro/power/shell" directly to the code not like what you have mentioned. The path should be given explicitly to the code given.@beepmap

Comment: @Vikram So you want to write down the path in the script instead of passing it as an argument right ?

Comment: Still i'm not getting it, how could I fit that in my code. can you please take this path "app/retro/power/shell" and show me how to give explicitly . And what about the 2nd and 3rd line of code. I'm new to shell script and not getting the meaning of the code too.

Comment: @Vikram So I edited it again. As you can see the first line of this script is setting the two variables (SRC_FILE and BKP_FILE) to the values that you mentioned. The second line will echo your SRC_FILE variable. The third line will echo your BKP_FILE variable.

Comment: @Vikram Don't hesitate to ask if you need more precise explanation, I'll help you :)